# autoselect select options with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, select

I am working on a function in Javascript/jQuery.
The function will search for usernames in the "select" element "Y" and selects them  whene you copied a bunch of usernames in the textarea "X" with '**,** ', '**,**', '**;**' or ' ' as separator and also if you do it the other way around:

javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("dd#id-element select#id").attr({"multiple": "multiple", "size": 25, "name": "id[]"});
});
$(function() {
    $("select#id").change(function() {
                    var selected_id = $(this).val(),
                            selected_name = new Array();
                    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
                        selected_name.push($(this).text());

                    });

                    $("textarea#id_field").val(selected_id);
                    $("textarea#name_field").val(selected_name);
                    console.log(selected_id, selected_name);
                });
                $("textarea#name_field").keyup(function() {
        $("select#id option").removeAttr("selected");
        var names_raw = $(this).val(),
            names = names_raw.replace(/(, | |,)/gi, ";"),
            selected_name = names.split(";"),
            selected_id = new Array();
        $.each(selected_name, function(i, value) {
            if (value != "" && value != null) {
                $("select#id option[label='" + value + "']").attr("selected", true);
                selected_id.push($("select#id option[label='" + value + "']").val());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<select name="id" id="id">
                        <option value="1092" label="00lara00">00lara00</option>
                        <option value="5105" label="010201e">010201e</option>
                        <option value="1725" label="0411dennis">0411dennis</option>
                        <option value="1795" label="051259">051259</option>
                        <option value="2281" label="0815Timmey">0815Timmey</option>
                        <option value="3337" label="0vlinder0">0vlinder0</option>
                        <option value="127" label="1001gece">1001gece</option>
                        <option value="3693" label="111nizza">111nizza</option>
                        <option value="821" label="114helen">114helen</option>
                        <option value="2887" label="1212whopper">1212whopper</option>
                        <option value="5564" label="123boo">123boo</option>
</select>
<textarea name="name_field" id="name_field"></textarea>
```

when i select some usernames in the select element, it works fine, the usernames are copied to the textarea.
when i paste some usernames in the textarea, everything is deselected like it should, but there is nothing new selected

Comment: I changed <select name="id" id="id"> to <select multiple="true" name="id" id="id"> and it looks like it works for me...does that help?

Comment: sorry forgot some example code. this form is loaded from zend frameworks, so i added this `$(document).ready(function() {
                    $("dd#id-element select#id").attr({"multiple": "multiple", "size": 25, "name": "id[]"});
                });
                ` to the <script> element, but still no good

Comment: I added that to my test, and it's working in my test, so I'm guessing that something else (perhaps from Zend Framework) is causing things to get off.
See my test here: http://jsfiddle.net/c4FZP/ - it looks like it's working there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. This is how I did it

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("dd#id-element select#id").attr({"size": 25});
});
$(function() {
    $("select#id").change(function() {
        var selected_id = $(this).val(),
                selected_name = new Array();
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
            selected_name.push($(this).text());
            $(this).addClass("checked");
        });
        $("textarea#name_field").val(selected_name);
        $("textarea#name_field").keyup();
    });
    $("textarea#name_field").keyup(function() {
        $("select#id option.checked").attr("checked", null).attr("selected", null).removeClass("checked");
        var names_raw = filterValue($(this).val()),
                names = names_raw.replace(/(, | |,|\s)/gi, ";"),
                selected_name = names.split(";"),
                selected_id = new Array();
        $(this).val(names_raw)
        $.each(selected_name, function(i, value) {
            if (value != "" && value != null) {
                if ($("select#id option[label='" + value + "']").length > 0) {
                    $("select#id option[label='" + value + "']").attr('checked', 'checked').attr('selected', 'selected').addClass("checked").focus();
                    selected_id.push($("select#id option[label='" + value + "']").val());
                }
            }
        });
        $("select#id").val(selected_id);
    });
});
```

html code:

```
<select name="id[]" id="id" multiple="multiple">
                                <option value="1092" label="00lara00">00lara00</option>
                                <option value="5105" label="010201e">010201e</option>
                                <option value="1725" label="0411dennis">0411dennis</option>
                                <option value="1795" label="051259">051259</option>
                                <option value="2281" label="0815Timmey">0815Timmey</option>
                                <option value="3337" label="0vlinder0">0vlinder0</option>
                                <option value="127" label="1001gece">1001gece</option>
                                <option value="3693" label="111nizza">111nizza</option>
                                <option value="821" label="114helen">114helen</option>
                                <option value="2887" label="1212whopper">1212whopper</option>
                                <option value="5564" label="123boo">123boo</option>
 </select>
 <textarea name="name_field" id="name_field"></textarea>
```